# showing custom dialog gives force close

Tags: android, android-dialog

i want to show custom dialog with given size and given postion.
first time when i click style btn it shows perfect what i want but open next time gives force close. below is error what i got in logcat:

```
     12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1976)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1871)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1851)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:365)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:206)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:251)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:307)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:225)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at com.nga.swp.MainActivity$44.onClick(MainActivity.java:1785)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-06 09:50:34.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(414):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

following below code snippet i am using:

```
style.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Font")
                .setView(childViewstyle)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int position) {
                                style.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_style_off);
                            }
                        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = 250;
        lp.height = 360;
        lp.x = -100;
        lp.y = -90;
        alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace

Comment: @newgenapps what is childViewstyle type is?Your Problem is like when you create Alert Dialog you need to remove items from parent's first.

Comment: AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

Comment: @newgenapps Your Real problem is childViewstyle which you set in Your Alert Dialog .can you give what is that childview is ,i means is listview type or any thing else.

Comment: @Herry LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);      View childViewstyle = inflater.inflate(R.layout.style, null); childViewstyle inflate an xml file

Comment: @newgenapps  so problem is when you create First Time alertDialog is use Your childViewstyle  in Builder that will Work good for First Time but when you again Come to Create is Force Close because when that already childViewstyle   in that Dialog which we are not Remove when again come for dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you create ALertDialog builder in onCreate Method and AlertDialog declares globally. Later you have to call `alertDialog.show();` whenever you need the dialog. No need to create an alert dialog for every button click.

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

move those lines after the last line:

```
 alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```